# How can I add two or more file attachments using %Net.MailMessage in intersystems-cache?

Tags: file, email-attachments, intersystems-cache, objectscript

I've tried this:

```
s status=msg.AttachFile("F:\MyDir","myFirstFile.pdf",1,.count)
s status=msg.AttachFile("F:\MyDir","mySecondFile.pdf",1,.count)
```

I want to add two or more attached files. But it's not working at all...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've found an answear: https://community.intersystems.com/post/how-can-i-add-two-or-more-file-attachments-netmailmessage